# Background size for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, background-size

I'm trying to make a background image for mobile devices like:

```css
body {
  background: url("/resources/img/background2.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

In Chrome developers' tools it looks nice, but on a real device (with a smaller screen size) it does not. Why is this, and how I can solve this problem?

Snapshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload snapshots?

Comment: @SherKhan yes, I updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a responsive background image which can get scaled down on smartphones. Use this:

```css
background-image:url('/resources/img/background2.jpg');
-webkit-background-size: 100%; 
-moz-background-size: 100%; 
-o-background-size: 100%; 
background-size: 100%; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```css
background-image: url("/resources/img/background2.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: In this case, only half of the picture screen

Comment: It means it is not in the same ratio as screen. You can use media queries to serve different images for different screen sizes and device orientations but part of the image will pretty much always be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution

```
body {
    background: url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-size: calc(100vw) calc(100vh);
    -moz-background-size: calc(100vw) calc(100vh);
    -o-background-size: calc(100vw) calc(100vh);
    background-size: calc(100vw) calc(100vh);
    }
```